# Runner cannot clone gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab, runner

The runner installed on my machine cannot clone the git repository.

I have a gitlab instance that runs as dockerized and expose the access to the web interface at http://172.19.193.16:666 address. At port 80 runs another completely different web page.

Gitlab suggest to clone the code with this url http://c87aa950bc8a/yamil.ortega/aprendizajegit.git 
but I changed to http://172.19.193.16:666/yamil.ortega/aprendizajegit.git and can do it.

Shared runners are disable, and I registered this only runner.

[image]

I register and installed the runner in another computer trying to make a simple CI pipeline. My toml file looks like this.

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "RunnerParaDotNet"
  url = "http://http://172.19.193.16:666/"
  token = "JTJxZ_xcxnzbs89Vcq_x"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.custom]
    run_exec = ""
```

When I add a new pipeline and the runner runs, I got the following message

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.1.0 (de7731dd)
  on RunnerParaDotNet JTJxZ_xc
Using Shell executor...
Running on CTISMXL8310VN7...
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/JTJxZ_xc/0/yamil.ortega/aprendizajegit/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@c87aa950bc8a/yamil.ortega/aprendizajegit.git/': Could not resolve host: c87aa950bc8a
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I added the line

```
172.19.193.16        c87aa950bc8a
```

to my hosts file inside C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and now I got this error.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.1.0 (de7731dd)
  on RunnerParaDotNet JTJxZ_xc
Using Shell executor...
Running on CTISMXL8310VN7...
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/JTJxZ_xc/0/yamil.ortega/aprendizajegit/.git/
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@c87aa950bc8a/yamil.ortega/aprendizajegit.git/' not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

So, I know that I can contact the Gitlab server (modifing the host file) with alias c87aa950bc8a but since it´s on port 666 , the runner cannot clone. 
Can I try something else?

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution.
Reading about advanced runners configuration in this page
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

found that I must add the

```
clone_url
```

instruction to the config.toml file

So, mi config.toml file looks like this

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "RunnerParaDotNet"
  url = "http://172.19.193.16:666/"
  token = "JTJxZ_xcxnzbs89Vcq_x"
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  clone_url = "http://172.19.193.16:666/"
[runners.custom_build_dir]
[runners.cache]
[runners.cache.s3]
[runners.cache.gcs]
[runners.custom]
run_exec = ""
```